# An application of two 3x3 matrices identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, applications

What is the proper context or the physical meaning for the following problem?
In particular, is it related to a classical equation?

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $3\times3$ matrices, such that $\det A=1$ and $B=A+A^{-1}$, then:
$$
4+\det B=Tr(B^2).
$$

Comment: The proper context is linear algebra, a basic area in mathematics and physics.

Comment: What do you mean? It seems you tagged this "Linear Algebra" yourself, so clearly you know what area of mathematics this is.. so what is the question?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is the problem related to a classical equation?

Comment: @Lovsovs Can you be more specific. It's a 3D equation...

Comment: I don't know much about physics here, but I would rather think of the Cayley-Hamilton equation $B^3+\ldots+\det(B)I=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation appears rather bizarre, and I would be surprised to see a "physical meaning" in any reasonable sense of the word "physical".  You might note, though, that if $A$ has nonzero eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ (counted by algebraic multiplicity), so that $\det(A) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3$, then $B$ has eigenvalues 
$\lambda_i + \lambda_i^{-1}$, and the equation becomes

$$ 4 + \prod_{i=1}^3 (\lambda_i + \lambda_i^{-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^3 (\lambda_i + \lambda_i^{-1})^2 \tag{1}$$

Now the difference between the two sides turns out to be 
$$ \dfrac{(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 \lambda_3)(\lambda_2 - \lambda_1 \lambda_3)(\lambda_3 - \lambda_1 - \lambda_2)(1 - \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3)}{ \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2^2 \lambda_3^2} $$

So in particular this is $0$ if $\det(A) = 1$.

EDIT:  Now, how could one come up with such a bizarre equation?  I'll try some reverse engineering.  I think the appropriate context is the elementary symmetric functions.

Multiplying by the common denominator $\lambda_1^2 \lambda_2^2 \lambda_3^2$, 
 equation (1) becomes an equation in symmetric polynomials:

$$ 4 \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2^2 \lambda_3^2 + \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 \prod_{i=1}^3 (\lambda_i^2+1) = \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2^2 \lambda_3^2 \sum_{i=1}^3 (\lambda_i^2 + 1)^2\lambda_i^{-2}$$

We can express each of these symmetric polynomials in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials $s_1 = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3$, $s_2 = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 + \lambda_1 \lambda_3 + \lambda_2 \lambda_3$, $s_3 = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3$:

$$ \eqalign{ q_1 = \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2^2 \lambda_3^2 &= s_3^2 \cr
q_2 = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 \prod_{i=1}^3 (\lambda_i^2+1) &= s_3 (s_3^2-2 s_1 s_3+s_1^2+(s_2-1)^2)\cr
q_3 = \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2^2 \lambda_3^2 \sum_{i=1}^3 (\lambda_i^2 + 1)^2\lambda_i^{-2} &= s_2^2-2 s_1 s_3+(s_1^2-2 s_2+6) s_3^2}$$
How do we get a linear combination of these that is $0$ when $s_3 = 1$?
Take the equation $a q_1 + b q_2 + c q_3 = 0$, and substitute $s_3 = 1$:

$$\eqalign{ 0 = a &+ b (1 - 2 s_1 + s_1^2 + (s_2-1)^2) + c (s_2^2 - 2 s_1 + s_1^2 - 2 s_2 + 6\cr & =(b+c) s_1^2 - 2 (b+c) s_ 1+(b+c) s_2^2 - 2(b+c)s_2+a+2 b+6 c} $$ 
To make this $0$ for all $s_1$ and $s_2$, we take $c=-b$ and $a=4b$.  With $b=1$ this corresponds to equation (1).

Comment: Agree, it seems to be in the realm of symmetric polynomials...

Comment: Even though the statement of OP is only true for 3 by 3 matrices...